# How do I access field variables directly in Drupal 7 without having to drill down into a node array?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a view reference field and have some php code in the view where it grabs the taxonomy ID of the page its currently on. Currently I am grabbing the TID via

```
menu_get_object()->field_device_type_vocabulary[und][0][tid];
```

I know you can access the fields directly without having to do that, but forgot how that was done.

Comment: BTW, you have a subtle error in that line of code.  The `[und]` should be quoted, eg `['und']`.  PHP will consider it a string automagically, but will throw a warning.

Comment: Clive's answer also fixes the following errors in reference to the same question but expanded:


http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75624/what-other-way-can-you-reference-a-variable-without-getting-the-following-error?noredirect=1#comment83708_75624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main methods:

1. Procedural, using [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), e.g.

   ```
   $node = menu_get_object();
   if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_device_type_vocabulary')) {
     $tid = $items[0]['tid'];
   }
   ```
2. Objected oriented, using an [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityMetadataWrapper/7), e.g.

   ```
   $node = menu_get_object();
   $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
   $tid = $wrapper->field_device_type_vocabulary[0]->tid->value();
   ```

Comment: seems like menu_get_object() has to be called regardless. i thought there was a variable something to field_field_name[value] or something of that sort.